# Data source of webpage not in Fetch/XHR

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to find the data source for this webpage, so that I can scrape and send warnings on heat stress automatically. Specifically, I am looking for the data source for "WBGT (C): 25.4" in the screenshot. I have tried to look at the Fetch/XHR responses, but it simply gives "ok". Is the data source cloaked/concealed? Or am I looking in the wrong place? Thank you!

http://www.weather.gov.sg/heat-stress/

[image]

Comment: ...is there a reason you don't have direct access to their data via a real-life business/org relationship? Scraping data is what people do when there's no better option - but if this for an emergency alert service, then clearly something's going wrong with your org...

Comment: The data is available via an app, unfortunately no API. I am trying to find a way to get the data directly, and continuously, so that we can make sure the alerts reach everyone in our team as soon as the data is updated and exceeds the threshold. Am I right to say it is impossible to identify the source in the webpage?

Comment: The data you're after is hardcoded into the rendered HTML for the page in the server-response. No AJAX/`fetch` is necessary, just DOM manipulation.

Comment: Specifically, it's stored as HTML-in-a-`string` (wtf) inside the various `<span class="sgr points">` elements's `data-content=""` attributes.#

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I’ve offered what I have below as “solution”, though it is not elegant, I admit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, it works and I understand it, though I must admit it is not very elegant.

```
url = 'http://www.weather.gov.sg/heat-stress/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
child_soup = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "map-container-lg"})
pattern = r'data-content=".*?Location: <strong>Jurong Stadium</strong></li>.*?WBGT \(℃\): (\d+\.\d+).*?onclick="showByClickSpan\(\'S132\'\)'
text=str(child_soup)
wbgt = text.split('Jurong Stadium', 1)[1]
wbgt = wbgt.split('WBGT (℃): ', 1)[1]
WBGT= float(wbgt.split('&lt',1)[0])
print(WBGT)
```